# I have one custom field (input text)that field allow only numeric value i need if i given text shown error in visual froce page with controller?

Tags: apex, inputtext

I have one custom field it allows only numeric value only. please send conditional formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an interesting way to solve the problem, 
I came across a simpler way using the APEX controller extesntion class. 
I used the following code in the extension class to check if the value is numeric or not.

```
boolean check = pattern.matches('[a-zA-Z]+',stringname);
if (check == true) {
the error message you want to display
}
```

I used this because it was easier to use without much change to my existing codes.

Comment: If this answer help you in any manner than mark this as correct answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple validation rule to prevent entering text characters.

Formula for validation rule:

```
NOT( ISNUMBER(field_api_name__c) )
```

[Visualforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)

Comment: sorry Mr ashwani how to write code in visualforce page & Controller because i am new in salesforce